# Is there a reward for re-completing Hell's Precipice mission?

Tags: pc, guild-wars

Does anyone know if there is now a reward for completing this mission again? Essentially re-completing the Prophecies campaign?

I can't find any info here, http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Hell's_Precipice or here, http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Category:Prophecies-related_lists

Anyone have an ideas? Otherwise I'll just go do the mission again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you now get a [Deldrimor Talisman](http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Deldrimor_Talisman) which can be turned into a variety of green items.  This is a one time thing and even if you have done the campaign before hand, you can get the reward if you recomplete it once.